# Belgium Schengen visa with Chinese passport

Tags: visas, schengen, chinese-citizens

I have a Chinese passport but live in the US on green card.

Can tourist visa for a trip to Belgium for a conference be acquired at Belgium Consulate in Atlanta? What are requirements, cost, and timeline? Will travel from USA to Paris to Brussels.

Comment: Note when filling out the application form that a trip for a conference is generally considered _business_ rather than _tourism_. Checking the wrong box would probably not in itself lead to a refusal, but could at least delay the processing of the application.

Answer (score 4):

The Belgian mission in Atlanta is accredited as a "[Consulate General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consul_(representative)#Consul_General)". Accordingly, it is entitled to issue visas, including the Schengen Short-stay visa.  This authority includes qualifying Chinese nationals, both with green card and without.

They advise...

> We advise 3 weeks before the intended departure date.

...and

[image]

See [Embassy and Consulates of Belgium in the United States](http://unitedstates.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/visa-belgium/visitors) and follow the appropriate links therein.